# Force-stopping, disabling and even factory reset failed to stop recurring app crash error message

Tags: system-error

My friend sold a TeXet 9768HD to somebody. Now the customer returned it with a weird problem. When the tablet boots up and loads OS (Jellybean.rus.texet 4.2.2), it shows:

> Unfortunately fingerprint unlock has stopped working.

It shows this error nonstop. Every time I tap on "OK" it comes back in a blink, with lots of pain! I went to Settings → Apps and saw this "FingerPrint Unlock" there, but like system apps it doesn't have "Remove/Uninstall" option. I can't install anything on it, because this error message is on the screen all the time. So I tried to use both "Force Stop" and "Disable" options, but regardless of that the error still comes up.

I've no idea what to do. My friend asked me to flash it, but since (obviously) TeXet no longer is active, there's no support.

"Wipe/factory reset" and "Clear cache" in recovery didn't solve the problem too.

When I plugged it to PC, it wasn't recognized, but after installing "Rockchip Tool" not Flashing tools seems to show it.

So, what's causing the issue and what do you suggest me to solve the issue?

Comment: Disabling the app should work.